# Riemannian manifold, Sobolev space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces

Let $(S, \sigma)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $dim \ S \leq 3$. I read in a paper:

Then $L^6(S, \sigma)$ is embedded in $H_1(S, \sigma)$.

My questions:

- What is the definition of $H_1$? I know that $H^1:= W^{1,2}$. Is it just a convention?
- Why do we have this embedding? I know about the Sobolev embedding but this would give requirements, when $H^m \subset L^p$.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I would guess $H_1$ is another notation for your $H^1 = W^{1,2}$, but you should see how the paper defines $H_1$. And yes, Sobolev embedding gives $W^{1,2} \subseteq L^6$ since $\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}$. Are you sure that's not the embedding the paper claims?

Comment: The paper says "The space $L^6 (S,\sigma) $ is then embedded in the Sobolev space
$H^ 1 (S,σ)$". Is it maybe just my english, did I understand it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, $H^1(S,\sigma)$ is chosen to refer to the completion in the $W^{1,2}(S,\sigma)$-norm of the smooth functions on $(S,\sigma)$. The Sobolev space $W^{1,2}(S,\sigma)$ is very often defined by means of weak derivatives. Under assumptions on the regularity of the domain, one can show that $H^1(S,\sigma) = W^{1,2}(S,\sigma)$.

Concerning your second question, it is related to the Sobolev embedding which holds for manifolds like [this wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality) page says

> The Sobolev embedding theorem holds for Sobolev spaces W k,p(M) on other suitable domains M. In particular (Aubin 1982, Chapter 2; Aubin 1976), [...].

An other reference on Sobolev Space on manifolds is *Sobolev Spaces on Riemannian Manifolds* by Emmanuel Hebey where you will find the embedding explicitly.